# How do I continue address sanitizer when SEGV on unknown address happens?

Tags: address-sanitizer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0f3x.png)

I already add ASAN_OPTIONS='halt_on_error=0', but it just aborts.

Comment: welcome! please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please don't ask question with pictures, when they are picture of text. Just paste the text instead.

Comment: This may not be a good example, but the question is valid, especially if you have a platform specific unit test that causes a segfault on purpose in a test.

Answer (score 0):

Your program did something like this:

```
const char *s = getenv("FOO");  // May return NULL
std::string str(p);             // Will crash if p is NULL
```

> How do I continue

You don't: your program *is* crashing. You'll have to fix the bug first.